# Создать iframe на js

Tags: javascript

Я хочу создать свой iframe. Мне надо его сделать так: мне надо создать ссылку на iframe(ссылку сделать на js), при встраивание этой ссылки на сайт появлялся, какой-либо блок с текстом html. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: что такое "ссылка на iframe"?

Comment: @ Igor  ссылка вот такая <iframe src="любая-ссылка"

Answer (score 1):

```js
function createFrame() {
  var fr = document.createElement("iframe");
  fr.src = "ссылка";
  document.body.appendChild(fr);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createFrame()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в коде страницы есть iframe, то задать ему документ-источник можно так:

```
frames[0].location.href='ссылка';
```

Индекс может быть другим, если у Вас несколько фреймов.