# Сделать ссылку для iframe

Tags: php, javascript

У меня есть онлайн редактор. Там я хочу сделать одну фишку, но я не знаю, как ее сделать. После того, как кто-то написал код в textarea, я хочу сделать кнопку "получить код" или "поделиться кодом". Мне надо, чтобы каждый раз после сохранения кода, ты мог код получить в iframe(ты написал код, например `<p>Hello</p>` и, чтобы этот код выводился в iframe). Я знаю, как это сделать, но вот, как сделать ссылку на iframe.Как? Может каждый раз после сохранения кода его как-то автоматически в новый файл пересылать и в iframe src выводить эту ссылку? Может на php можно сделать или на js? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Элемент iframe является обычным узлом DOM, как и любой другой. `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]`

Comment: Вы, кажется, забыли отметить галочкой ответ, который Вам уже дали: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848461