# Как разместить html в iframe

Tags: javascript

Я создал iframe. Хочу в iframe добавить html текст. Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
function createFrame() {
  var fr = document.createElement("iframe");
  fr.src = "";
  fr.width = "30%";
  fr.height = "300px";
  document.body.appendChild(fr);
}
createFrame();
```

Comment: Вы, кажется, забыли отметить галочкой ответ, который Вам уже дали: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848461

Comment: @Igor мне не дали ответ

Comment: @ДенисЛу вообще-то дали, даже два

Answer (score 0):

> "Не корысти ради."

```
function createFrame() {
  var fr = document.createElement("iframe");
  fr.src = "about:blank";
  fr.width = "30%";
  fr.height = "100px";
  document.body.appendChild(fr);

  fr.contentWindow.document.write("<p>Hello, world!</p>");
  fr.contentWindow.document.write("<p>Hello, Денис!</p>");
}
createFrame();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qo29chus/2/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4mrepvaz/

```js
function createFrame() {
  var fr = document.createElement("iframe");
  fr.width = "30%";
  fr.height = "300px";
  document.body.appendChild(fr);
  fr.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Hi!</h1>"
}

createFrame();
```

PS: Без сниппета, т. к. тут настройки безопасности не позволяют этому коду работать.